# Equivalent of "Scan For Hardware Changes" in device manager doesn't work after failed installation

Tags: windows, driver, installation, inf, device-manager

According to the [docs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259697/en-us) the C++ functions `CM_Locate_DevNodeA` and `CM_Reenumerate_DevNode` of `CfgMgr32.dll` should be the programatical equivalant to the menu item *scan for changed hardware* in the device manager.

See [2nd answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181525/is-there-an-api-call-to-start-a-scan-for-hardware-devices/2186058) for managed code in C#.

But in contrary to the docs, the programmatical approach doesn't work always, when the Device manager operation works. This is my case:

1. User already plugged in the USB device
2. No driver found
3. My installer adds the right INF-File into the
   Windows/inf directory
4. `CM_Reenumerate_DevNode` doesn't cause the installation of the new    driver
5. Wheras "Scan for hardware changes" in device manager starts    the
   installation with the new driver

Comment: Did you find an answer?  I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The driver gets recognized after reboot, when using `SetupCopyOEMInf` (C# example in accepted answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659223/install-libusb-driver-using-inf-file-with-c-sharp)) instead of copying the inf file to the C:\windows\inf directory. This method seems to be the equivalent of "Right click on inf file --> Install".

In my case the window "Windows can't verify the publisher of this driver software" came up because the manufacturer didn't register it. But this is a different story. However, this could have been another cause for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to write C++ code to replicate the Device Manager's Scan For Hardware command.

I tried using the code at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/259697.

However, it didn't work.  I noticed `CM_Reenumerate_DevNode` returned `CR_ACCESS_DENIED`, which is `#define CR_ACCESS_DENIED  (0x00000033)   // NT ONLY` in `Cfgmrg32.h`.

According to [CM_Reenumerate_DevNode function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539763%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), callers of this function need `SeLoadDriverPrivilege`.

To get around setting this privilege in code, I ran the .exe as an administrator by right-clicking on .exe and selecting Run as administratror.