# How can I install the INF driver without the [DefaultInstall] section from a .NET desktop application?

Tags: c#, c++, libusb, inf, winusb

I have created a driver for a composite device (hardware ID with an MI_## part) based on [WinUsbDriver](http://libusb-winusb-wip.googlecode.com/files/winusb%20driver.zip).

The point is that "template" does not contains the **[DefaultInstall]** section, for that reason I can't *P/Invoke InstallHinfSection* function:

```
InstallHinfSection(NULL,NULL,TEXT("DefaultInstall 132 path-to-inf\infname.inf"),0);
```

I want to create the INF files and install them using the application code, before connecting the composite device for the first time.

How can I install the INF Driver without the **[DefaultInstall]** section from a .NET desktop application?

Comment: Why don't you just add it?  INF files are like cookies, you can simply bake another one.  Do note the DeviceInstall subdirectory in the [.NET version](https://winusbnet.codeplex.com/), the DeviceInstall.cpp source code file shows you how to use SetupCopyOEMInf().

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your comment. I'm using [LibUsbDotNet](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html). The INF files are based on [WinUsbDriver](http://libusb-winusb-wip.googlecode.com/files/winusb%20driver.zip) template. 
I found a way to create a self-signed .cat files from .inf using [dpscat](https://code.google.com/p/usb-travis/source/browse/trunk/libusbK/src/dpscat/dpscat.txt) and then **dpint.exe**(from Windows) comes into _game_.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751075/1948857](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751075/1948857) May be this answer can help. I came acroos these problem these days and solved with these answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet (in Windows Vista and later) is to use a direct function that installs the inf into the Driver Store, then automatically installs it on matching hardware. This can be done with one function: [DiInstallDriver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544717.aspx).

For example...

```
[DllImport("newdev.dll")]
public static extern bool DiInstallDriver
(
    [In] IntPtr hwndParent,
    [In] string FullInfPath,
    [In] uint Flags,
    [Out] bool NeedReboot
);

DiInstallDriver(IntPtr.Zero, "full path to my inf", 0, false);
```